# Laravel: Duplicar projeto em mesmo diretório

Tags: laravel, apache, route

Bom dia pessoal!
Tenho uma API do laravel em um servidor na pasta `/www/var/html/api1`, por segundos motivos tenho que construir outra API no mesmo servidor, então eu dupliquei a que eu tinha para facilitar`/www/var/html/api2`.

Até aí tudo bem, só que quando fui simular um POST na api2, ele sempre é redirecionado para a api1, não entendo muito bem sobre rotas e não sei se o apache tem algo a ver. Alguem tem alguma ideia do que pode estar fazendo que qualquer requisição que eu envie para esse servidor seja tratada pela api1?

Tentei criar um arquivo avulso na pasta `/www/var/html/` e chamar ele, abriu uma página do laravel informando `the page you are looking for could not be found.`

Comment: Veja se no arquivo de rotas as requisições feitos pro seu `\` não são redirecionadas para a API 1.

Comment: Você diz na api2? Não entendi

Comment: Ah agora que vi que você duplicou os diretórios. Nesse caso vê na config do seu apache se não tem um `Redirect` para a API1